# Establish call tree for C code

Tags: c, unix, callstack

I have a large code written in C, but I did not write all of it myself. I wish to create an overview of the call structure in the code for reference. That is: I wish to know what (non-standard) functions are called by the different functions in the code, and thus create a hierarchy or a tree of the different functions. Are there any free, Unix compatible programs (that means no Visual Studio, but a Vim plugin or such would be neat) that can do this, or will I have to write something that can do this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an overview of available tools see 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph

There is a Vim plugin C Call-Tree Explorer called CCTree
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368

Comment: Very nice list. I also like the CCTree plugin for Vim. Do you happen to know how to collapse a list?

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen does that too, it has to be enabled though.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned a Vim plug-in, check out http://sites.google.com/site/vimcctree/. It uses CScope to generate the tree, so you will need to first generate a CScope db of your source files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.gson.org/egypt/ This uses GCC to process the code and extracts the interdependencies within the program from the AST it emits.

Answer (score 1):

gprof will do that. It also generates an execution profile, but in doing so it creates a call tree.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded SourceTrail (https://github.com/CoatiSoftware/Sourcetrail/releases) and it did what I wanted, which was pretty close to what I think you want.

(What I wanted was to find out what routines called the function I was considering changing, or needed to understand).

Note that it is no longer maintained, but it did exactly what I wanted.  It runs under Windows and Linux, and made finding who calls a function pretty trivial (as well as following that function's call tree down as needed). If you care, it has a GUI (is a GUI? whatever).

It does the parsing itself, but it didn't take very long to run, perhaps about the same time or a little less than compiling the code.

But if you want text only, or don't want to use a gui, or don't want to have it scan the code, this isn't for you.

(Notes - in my case, I was hyper-focused on one or 2 functions, and didn't care what system functions were being called.  I spent some time stubbing out all the include files that were needed (since I ran the parse on one machine (A Linux machine) that didn't have all the include files needed for the Windows program I was looking at, and then did the exploration on a different (Windows) machine.  Which, I should mention, worked perfectly.  I just copied the entire source tree from my Linux machine to my Windows machine (which included the Sourcetail project file), loaded Sourcetail and had it load the project - done.)